# Rails devise before_filter authenticate_user! guide to sign up path instead of sign in path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using Rails devise. Applying `before_filter authenticate_user!` to a controller is pretty magical and almost offers the exact redirect solution I am looking for. However!-- I'd prefer that when clicking a link blocked by `authenticate_user!`, the user be redirect to the `new_user_registration_path` (sign up), instead of the `new_user_session_path` (sign in).

Is there a way to easily customize devise to allow for this?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

We can use [store_location_for](http://Stores%20the%20provided%20location%20to%20redirect%20the%20user%20after%20signing%20in.)  which stores the provided location to redirect the user after signing in.

---

In your `application_controller.rb` add

```
protected

def authenticate_user!
    unless user_signed_in?
    store_location_for(:user, request.url)
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```

And in your controller you can add:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :unless => :devise_controller? #   This prevent the infinite redirects.
```

This code above will do the trick for specific controller as you mentioned in your question, and redirect user to sign up page instead of login page. If you would like to use only on certain links in your view you can check the code I posted below EDIT.

**EDIT**

---

You can simple check if `!current_user` and when user click on the link, it will be redirected to sign up page. This code below will return user to the previous page for sure. You can put the code below to your views, and use `if else` as well:

```
<% if !current_user %>
  <%= link_to 'Register', new_user_registration_path %>
<% end %>
```

**NOTE**
*before_filter syntax is deprecated in Rails 5.0 and will be removed in Rails 5.1*

Comment: This forces the correct sign up page, but fails to redirect the user back to their original destination the way that the off-the-shelf `before_filter :authenticate_user!` does

Comment: I updated my code so that you can authenticate user, and redirect him/her to sign up page instead of login page on specific controller. Would you like to redirect them after successfully signing up, back to the previous page? If you have some code please share, so that we can help you.

Comment: Check the updates, I refactored the code with store_location_for method

Answer (score 1):

In your `application_controller.rb` file:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user

def authenticate_user
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url unless user_signed_in?
end
```